How to pass nonce value to react-apex charts
I am implementing csp headers at nginx cong level. style-src is blocking and it not loading the styles of react apex charts
I want my webpage to load without any csp headers issue i cant use unsafe-inline regarding of OWASP

I am experiencing the same issue, were you able to resolve this ?
